# Fourier transform of $f(x) = \frac{x}{(1+x^2)^2}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

The Fourier transform is given by

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\hat{f}(\xi) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-i\xi x} dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{(1+x^2)^2} e^{-i\xi x} dx
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I have a hard time computing this integral. I have tried some substitutions but have gotten stuck every time. After getting stuck I have tried using some Fourier transform rules to simplify the problem. I define

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
g(x) = \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

for use with the rule

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
F[xg(x)] = i(\hat{g})^{'}(\xi)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

To help compute $\hat{g}$ I define

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
h(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

for use with the rule

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
F[f(x)g(x)] = \frac{1}{2\pi} (\hat{f}*\hat{g})(\xi)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

with $f=g$. To compute $\hat{h}$ I have tried using the rule

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
F \Big[\frac{1}{x^2 + a^2} \Big] = \frac{\pi}{a} e^{-a |\xi|}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

with $a=1$, which gives us

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\hat{h}(\xi) &= \pi e^{-|\xi|} \\
F[f(x)g(x)] &= F[h(x)^2] \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} (\hat{h}*\hat{h})(\xi) \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{h}(\xi - y) \hat{h}(y) dy \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \pi^2 e^{-|\xi - y|} e^{-|y|} dy \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{|y||\xi - y|} dy
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

This is where I get stuck again, since I have a hard time with this integral as well. I have tried removing the absolute values by considering different intervals, but no luck. I would be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let be $$g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$ and $$f(x)=-\frac12g'(x)=\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^2}$$
So we have $$F(\xi)=-\frac12\,i\xi\, G(\xi)$$

By duality theorem $\mathcal F\left\{\frac12\mathrm e^{-|x|}\right\}=\frac{1}{1+\xi^2}$ and then $\mathcal F\left\{\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right\}=\pi\,\mathrm e^{-|\xi|}=G(\xi)$

Hence
$$
F(\xi)=-\frac12\,i\xi\, G(\xi)=-\frac12\,i\xi\,\pi\,\mathrm e^{-|\xi|}
$$

Comment: Thank you for the help, but shouldn't $f(x)=-\frac{1}{2} g'(x)$ in the second equation?

Comment: Ops! you're right! corrected now

Comment: I think you should also change $-\frac{1}{2} \frac{x}{(1+x^2)^2}$ to $\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^2}$. Sorry if I am being pedantic, but I am unsure if it is bad form for me to edit your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: yes! thank you!